# Show array as checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: admin_user_path(@user.id) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
      <br>
      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
      <br>
      <%= f.label :tags %>
      <%= f.text_field :tags_string %> 
      <%= f.submit "update", placeholder: "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

@user.tags is an array of strings, with possible `["A","B","C"]` as possible tags. Some users have one, some have all of them...etc.

Being `tags_string` a method which converts tags in a string for having the user editing the form to change it if desired.

However, this is error prone, and I want the user to have the ability to chose between all possible tags having them in checkboxes.

What would I need to do in order to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first recommend using simple_form ([git:plataformatec/simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)) instead of form_for which will make this much easier for you!

You can write the form as:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: admin_user_path(@user.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :tags_string, as: :check_boxes, collection: ['A', 'B', 'C'] %> 
  <%= f.button :submit, value: 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

Voila, you are all set! Are you serializing the array of tags or is Tag a model that has_many Users?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Mongoid. That doesn't allow me to use simple_form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755726/rails-mongoid-simple-form-in-association-undefined-method-options-for-m#answer-9755824

Comment: Gotcha, then you can just use the [collection_check_boxes()](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) method inside the form_for! I'd use it like: `<%= collection_check_boxes(:tags_string, #method, TagsStrings.all, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: :tags_strings would work if TagsString is a model and User `has_many :tags_strings` but I'd need to know more about how the connection is set up (like I mentioned before, serialized array vs. related models) to give you a more exact answer.

Comment: : tags_strings is a method in User collection, returning the user tags as a string: ["A","B","C"] -> "A,B,C".

Answer (score 0):

You can probably loop possible tags and show the check-box for each tag.
Your modified code looks like:-

```
  <% @user.tags.each do |tag| %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'tags_string[]', tag.name -%>
        <%= tag.name -%>
  <% end %>
```

Documentation reference for showing checked or not and other options available:- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag